# geochart custom tooltip onchange

Tags: jquery, google-visualization

I am trying select region in google GeoChart with custom tooltip. Problem is that after option change tooltip not work. [here is example](http://jsfiddle.net/wwDyU/34/) which I use I don't understand how setColumns() works and does it change all table, or only one column ? What is zero (..[0,{...) ?

```
view.setColumns([0, {
        type: 'number',
        calc: function (dt, row) {
            //console.log(dt);
            return (dt.getValue(row, 0) == selectedState) ? 1 : 0;
        }
    }]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show which state is selected (color red) and have the same tooltip as before you can just add 2 column:

```
    view.setColumns([0, {
        type: 'number',
        calc: function (dt, row) {
            return (dt.getValue(row, 0) == selectedState) ? 1 : 0;
        }
    }, 2]);
```

See [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/antojurkovic/wwDyU/35/).

DataView is a reference to existing DataTable. With `setColumns()` you select columns which will be used for chart to be drawn. See [DataView reference](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataView) and `setColumn()`.